# Decoding body parameters with Spring

Tags: java, spring, slack, slack-api, spring-rest

I'm developing a REST API backend with Spring for a Slack App. I was able to receive messages from Slack (the slash commands) but I'm not able to properly receive component interactions (button clicks).

The [official documentation](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-buttons) says:

> Your Action URL will receive a HTTP POST request, including a payload body parameter, itself containing an application/x-www-form-urlencoded JSON string.

therefore I have written the following `@RestController`:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/actions", headers = {"content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
public ResponseEntity action(@RequestParam("payload") ActionController.Action action) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Action {

    @JsonProperty("type")
    private String type;

    public Action() {}

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

}
```

however I get the following error:

```
Failed to convert request element: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'controllers.ActionController$Action'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'controllers.ActionController$Action': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

What does it mean, and how to resolve?

Comment: two things. 1. Make Action a separate class instead of inner class. Jackson has some issue with deserializing to inner classes. 2 what is the body that is being sent to this endpoint.

Comment: The body being sent to this endpoint is `payload=%7B%22type%22%3A%22interactive_message%22%2C%22trigger_id%22%3A%22425937372067.385758389520.d1fe461bd1de87428efb097e09babee7%22%7D`

Comment: above string is part of the url? or is it part of POST message body? If its part of the url then solution is to do as @davidxxx suggested. If its part of Post Message payload, then use `@RequestBody` instead of  `@RequestParam` and spring will automatically convert that to Your Action class

Comment: @pvpkiran It is an interesting idea. Actually it is not the JSON that is posted { ... } directly in the body but it is a value of the payload parameter added in the body of the request. Do you think that Spring will be able to do the conversion all the same into the custom class ?

Comment: @davidxxx No Spring cannot do this if its not a json. because spring relies on Jackson to do the conversion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You receive a string that contains a JSON content. You don't receive a JSON input as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is used as content type and not `application/json` as stated :

> Your Action URL will receive a HTTP POST request, including a payload
>   body parameter, itself containing an application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   JSON string.

So change the parameter type to `String` and use Jackson or any JSON library to map the `String` to your `Action` class :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/actions", headers = {"content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
public ResponseEntity action(@RequestParam("payload") String actionJSON) {
    Action action = objectMapper.readValue(actionJSON, Action.class);  
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
}
```

As pvpkiran suggests, you could have replaced `@RequestParam` by `@RequestBody` if you could pass the JSON string directly in the body of the POST request, and not as a value of a parameter but it seems that is not the case there.
Indeed by using `@RequestBody`, the body of the request is passed through an `HttpMessageConverter` to resolve the method argument.

To answer to your comment, Spring MVC doesn't provide a very simple way to achieve your requirement : mapping the String JSON to your `Action` class.
But if you really need to automatize this conversion you have a lengthy alternative as stated in [the Spring MVC documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.0.RC2/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-typeconversion) such as Formatters (emphasis is mine) :

> Some annotated controller method arguments that represent String-based
>   request input — e.g. `@RequestParam`, `@RequestHeader`, `@PathVariable`,
>   `@MatrixVariable,` and `@CookieValue`, may require type conversion if the
>   argument is declared as something other than String.
>
> For such cases type conversion is automatically applied based on the
>   configured converters. By default simple types such as int, long,
>   Date, etc. are supported. **Type conversion can be customized through a
>   WebDataBinder, see DataBinder, or by registering Formatters with the
>   FormattingConversionService, see Spring Field Formatting.**

By creating a formatter (`FormatterRegistry` subclass) for your `Action` class you could add that in the Spring web config [as documented](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.0.RC2/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-conversion) :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        // ... add action formatter here
    }
}
```

and use it in your parameter declaration :

```
public ResponseEntity action(@RequestParam("payload") @Action Action actionJ) 
{...}
```

Comment: This actually works, but it looks to me like a workaround rather than a solution. Do Spring/Jackson really not have a way to automatically do the same?

Comment: @Andrea Unfortunately not. The automatic features depend on the other party's complying with standard ways of doing things, such as not double-encoding payloads for no sane reason.

Comment: I edited with a stupid thing. No idea really. Maybe chrylis is right.

Comment: @Andrea Not easy solution but you can automatize the JSON -> Action conversion.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, you could use the code block below. **@Request** body maps the the payload to the **Action** class. It also validates to make sure that the type is not blank. The **@Valid** and **@NotBlank** is from **javax.validation** package.

```
    @PostMapping("actions")
public ResponseEntity<?> startApplication(@RequestBody @Valid Action payload) {
    // use your payload here 
    return ResponseEntity.ok('done');
}


class Action {

    @NotBlank
    private String type;

    public Action() {
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```