# Spring can't properly decode form-urlencoded value

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, urlencode

I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52091841/decoding-body-parameters-with-spring) because my problem was similar to the question, but now I'm stuck.
Through Postman I'm sending data this way:

[image]

and in Spring I retrieve them like this:

```
@PostMapping(path = PathConstants.START_ACTION, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<BaseResponse<ProcessInstance>> start(@PathVariable String processDefinitionId,
            @RequestParam("username") String params) {
```

This was it's working, and I can print the value of the username:

```
System.out.println("Username " + params);
```

The problem is that I need all the params I'm sending, but I can't get them as a String or whatever other Object, since I will be making lots of different requests and not all of them have "username" field, and by the way I need to collect all of them.
How can I achieve this? 
I've tried doing

```
 @PostMapping(path = PathConstants.START_ACTION, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<BaseResponse<ProcessInstance>> start(@PathVariable String processDefinitionId,
            @RequestParam String params) {
```

or

```
@PostMapping(path = PathConstants.START_ACTION, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<BaseResponse<ProcessInstance>> start(@PathVariable String processDefinitionId,
             String params) {
```

as suggested in other answers, but in these cases params is null. What is the right way to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `@RequestBody` annotation in your method, and I would recommend using a `MultiValueMap`:

```
@PostMapping(path = PathConstants.START_ACTION, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<BaseResponse<ProcessInstance>> start(@PathVariable String processDefinitionId, @RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> params)
```